# How do I crop an image using wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I want to extract a subimage from a wxImage by using the two-point coordinates or one point and the size.

I assumed that [`Resize()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#Resize) was supposed to do that, but it looks that it doesn't give the desired results.

For example doing Resize(Size(10,10),Point(0,0)) will give me the right results top-left 10x10 subimage.

Now if I want to get something else I'm kinda lost in two-dimensional space ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `Resize()` works in ways that are not well explained :p

Here is the crop solution: `cropped = WxImage.GetSubImage(rect)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use wxPython in that way. But you could take the information you're getting and use the Python Imaging Library to do what you want: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ It supports cropping along with many other image manipulation techniques.

Comment: Why? How is the Resize supposed to work? I managed to get better results by giving negative Point coordinates.

Comment: Alright, the docs say "Changes the size of the image in-place without scaling it, by adding either a border with the given colour or cropping as necessary." Personally, I have never known anyone to use wx methods over PILs, but use whatever works best for your use case.